# Is there a python function for getting the ground truth communities?

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, graph-theory

I have the adjacency matrix for Zachary's karate club and the college football dataset. Is there a function to get the ground truth communities of a dataset? I tagged networkx and igraph because I'm open to all options. I got Zachary's ground truth communities because I looked online for pictures of the dataset and had to manually count the nodes out by hand, but for larger datasets this would be a problem. Surely there has to be an easier way

Answer (score 2):

The "ground truth" communities from the Karate Club network are easily accessible in the [networkx generator](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.social.karate_club_graph.html#networkx.generators.social.karate_club_graph):

```
import networkx as nx

zkc = nx.karate_club_graph()
gt_membership = [zkc.nodes[v]['club'] for v in zkc.nodes()]
```

Here, the two communities are labeled 'Mr. Hi' and 'Officer'.

The College Football network dataset, as well as several other seminal datasets in the network science literature, can be found on [Mark Newman's website](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/).

Comment: Will I be able to get the ground truth communities for the college football using the same/similar lines? @ComplexGates

Comment: Yes, the college football network on Newman's website contains the ground truth community labels.  There is an example for loading and processing on the networkx website: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/graph/plot_football.html